# Stop image slider forward button on last image in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I put an image slider on my website to show the image one by one on click event, but on the last image I want to stop image slider. I don't want to repeat image again and I don't want forward slide but we can go back.

```
   <script>    
    var slideIndex = 1;
    showDivs(slideIndex);

    function plusDivs(n) {
        showDivs(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function showDivs(n) {
        var i;
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
       if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
           x[i].style.display = "none";
       }
      x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
    <div class="w3-content w3-display-container"> 
    <div style="margin-left:150px"> 
    <img class="mySlides" src="../../../../../imageslider2/slide1.jpg" style="width:auto; height:auto"/> 
    <img class="mySlides" src="../../../../../imageslider2/slide2.jpg" style="width:auto; height:auto"/> 
    <pre> <a class="w3-btn-floating w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</a> 
    <a class="w3-btn-floating w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</a> 
    </div>
```

Comment: on the html code:i have this <div class="w3-content w3-display-container">
    <div style="margin-left:150px">
  <img class="mySlides" src="../../../../../imageslider2/slide1.jpg" style="width:auto; height:auto"/>
  <img class="mySlides" src="../../../../../imageslider2/slide2.jpg" style="width:auto; height:auto"/>
 
<pre>  <a class="w3-btn-floating w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</a>
  <a class="w3-btn-floating w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</a>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to get a count of the total number of slides and set it as a variable, which you can do with [.length](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_nodelist_length.asp) and then you need to add a conditional statement to your `plusDivs` function to do something(alert in the below example) if the `slideIndex` value is equal to that of the total number of slides:

```js
var slideIndex = 1,
    totalSlides = document.querySelectorAll('.mySlides').length;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  if (slideIndex === totalSlides) {
    alert('End of slideshow');
  } else {
    showDivs(slideIndex += n);
  }
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  if (n > x.length) { slideIndex = 1 }
  if (n < 1) { slideIndex = x.length }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<div class="w3-content w3-display-container"> 
  <div style="margin-left:150px"> 
    <img class="mySlides" src="http://placehold.it/250x250" style="width:auto; height:auto"/> 
    <img class="mySlides" src="http://placehold.it/250x250/000/fff" style="width:auto; height:auto"/> 
    <pre><a href="#" class="w3-btn-floating w3-display-left" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">❮</a> 
    <a href="#" class="w3-btn-floating w3-display-right" onclick="plusDivs(1)">❯</a> </pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could use the same approach to simply hide the previous or next buttons if they are at the start or the end of the slideshow.

Comment: but when we show alert message..both button is not working..forward and backward for image slider..i want disable only forward button